# .NET Go To Implementation of a NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, symbols

Is anyone aware of a method/tool that would allow me to **browse the implementation** of a method/type that comes from a NuGet package (by having the original *PDBs* or a *URL* of where to get them).

I am aware of [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/diagnostics/source_link.md), and I am, in fact, using it. However, source linking is a debugger feature that allows it to download source code while debugging. I need to be able to browse my source code without debugging. (Say by hitting F12 on some method).

Weirdly, SourceLink downloads a copy of the original source, so I only need to link visual studio to point to the source file.

I tried using *dotPeek* from *JetBrains*, but I only manged to get it working as a symbol server, which is again helpful - but only while debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that with JetBrains Resharper.

If your code is using an interface from a NuGet assembly - or from any assembly that is not your own - you have to press F12 - Go to definition - on the method you are interested in. This will navigate to the source code of the interface.
Then, you have to Ctrl + F12 - Go to implementation - to go to the implementation(s) of that interface in this assembly.
As far as I know, you can't use Ctrl + F12 directly from your code, because it would only search for implementations in your code.

Comment: Yes, all the stuff you mentioned above is correct. We will look into possibly purchasing ReSharper in the future, but until that moment occurs - we are looking for either a free tool or a visual studio feature that maybe we can write our own tool on top of. 

Still thaks for the info, at the end we are probably going to end up with ReSharper :)

Comment: won't this just decompile the file? in some case decompiled code will be slightly different from the original one. Plus all the comments and indentation will be stripped off

Comment: @arthur.borisow If configured correctly, Resharper first tries to locate the original PDB by downloading it from a symbol server.

Comment: is there any documentation on how to set everything up? preferably for f#?