# "Go to Implementation" ending up with "The symbol has no implementations"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

When right clicking on e.g. a method in Visual Studio and selecting `Go To Implementation` it tells me

> The symbol has no implementations

I tried with

```
services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesMovieContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesMovieContext")));
```

where AddDbContext is actually part of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions`

Is it possible to get `Go To Implementation` working, as .NET Core and ASP.NET Core are open source? I don't want to manually go to the Github repository for that. Ìf it's not directly possible with Visual Studio, are there maybe any plugins that make this possible?

For the sake of completeness: I am using Visual Studio 2019 Preview and .NET Core Preview 5.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in Visual Studio. It seems it is possible in the ReSharper IDE though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507517/3878764

Comment: For VS built-in feature, it is impossible, you could trace this issue [Expected behavior for Go To Definition for metadata references #24349](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24349)

Comment: Thanks, both hints were useful. Installed the Resharper extension and it works.

Answer (score 1):

> > I don't want to manually go to the Github repository for that. Ìf it's not directly possible with Visual Studio, are there maybe any plugins that make this possible?

If your only intention is to quickly browse data, and see code implementation, you can do this quickly using [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the ReSharper plugin for Visual Studio which decompiles source files or the Rider IDE by JetBrains. They are not free however.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to debug the .NET Core code directly through Visual Studio. You need to enable two things in order to achieve that.

1. Allow symbols to be loaded from Microsoft symbol servers.
2. Enable debugging for Microsoft' source code.

Both options are available in Visual Studio and no need to use external tools.

In order to allow symbols to be loaded from Microsoft symbol server you need to go to **Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> Symbols** you will find the symbol servers listed. Put a checkbox to **"Microsoft Symbol Servers"** like shown in the screen shot below

[image]

Then go to **Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> General** and check the option **"Enable .NET Framework for source stepping"** This will automatically disable the option **"Enable Just My Code"** which is fine.

[image]

At this point you still won't be able to examine Microsoft code by just selecting the code of interest and pressing **F12**. However, you can step into Microsoft's code using **F11** when debugging your application. This is the way it works.

**Note:** By enabling Microsoft's symbol servers like shown above will cause your Visual Studio to work way too slow. This is normal because of the many debugging symbols that needs to be downloaded from Microsoft' servers. So use this option only when you want to check something specific and disable it in your daily use.