# View ASP NET Core source code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Consider the following code:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItem),
    new { Id = item.id },
    item
);
```

I want to view the implementation of `CreatedAtAction`, so I right click on it and select `Go To Implementation` which gives me
[image]

So, any way to comfortably jump to areas of interest in the ASP Net Core source code? Or do I really have to look things up in the Github repository? ):

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383941/go-to-implementation-ending-up-with-the-symbol-has-no-implementations

Comment: Depends on what version of .Net Core - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626888/debug-net-core-source-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: thank you both, but I do not want to debug it, I want to be able to just browse the code.

Comment: The latter, I think.. unless you have the source code downloaded, built and referenced? https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs/ ? Or did I misunderstand the Q?

Comment: @CaiusJard I was wondering if this browsing is somehow possible in Visual Studio (with maybe some initial configuration) instead of switching over to Github. E.g. I know this from AndroidStudio and referenced libraries, where one can directly inspect their code. Quite useful.

Comment: Is it the same as [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670662/go-to-implementation-says-the-symbol-has-no-implem.html) reported bug?

Comment: You could use DotPeek by Jetbrains. This will decompile a dll